# Web API with SignalR

Tags: .net, signalr

I'm building a .net web application of multiplayer chess game, and I'm breaking my head over the most suitable technology for that purpose,

I was thinking of implementing WEB API for server side with SignalR to manage player's interactions and Jquery for client side

I would love to hear you guys please

Do you recommend otherwise ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that in particular. I would personally prefer angular over jQuery on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR seems suitable for your need. You should keep in mind that the websocket connection can be disconnected for various reason so you should handle the events and cases so you may consider maintaining your connection alive. You may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) for the detailed lifetime and other stuff.